# Can I add nodes to a 1-node cluster in Service Fabric?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

If I create standalone Service Fabric cluster with a single node, will it be possible to add nodes to it later? Per this document [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-capacity), scale out is not supported on one-node clusters, but I'm not sure if it's only applicable to SF clusters in Azure or standalone as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-windows-server-add-remove-nodes#add-nodes-to-your-cluster) for detailed instructions about how to add a new node to existing standalone cluster.

I would also emphasis the importance of point #7 in the above document - *To ensure consistency across different nodes in the cluster, you must initiate a configuration upgrade.* This is important to make sure that your initial configuration later can be used for [cluster configuration upgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-upgrade-windows-server#upgrade-the-cluster-configuration).